# How to control hardware back button

Tags: android

In my application, I want to control the hardware `back button`. That means in my app there are four or five activity. Now suppose I move from one activity to another.

Now in my case when I press the hardware back button I want my app to exit from any activity where I have been but in my app when the press this back button than it doesn't exit my app until it reaches the first activity... so my question is that what should I do so that when I press the hardware back button it will exit my app... please suggest me.

Comment: Ow, and I think typing "back" and "android" here on stackoverflow will give you a lot of similar hits....

Comment: Wow- how do you get these kinds of responses to your question and not even accept an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: but where i write this code means there are five activity in my app so in which activity i write this code..moreever in which event this code is executed

Comment: @Anshuman, this is what you want right here. You'll have to check for it in whatever the visible Activity is, and it will execute within that Activity. Then if you use this, it will start the new activity.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to store the instances of all 5 Activities in a common class, and add an `onBackPressed()` in every activity, which will call a method in the common class which will call `activity.finish()` on each of the 5 Activities.

For example:

```
class Activity1 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyController.getInstance().setActivity1(this);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        MyController.getInstance().closeAllActivities();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Similarly, write for Activity2, Activity3, and so on. And, MyController class would look like this:

```
class MyController {
    private static MyController instance;
    private Activity activity1, activity2, activity3, activity4, activity5;

    private MyController() {}
    public static synchronized MyController getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new MyController;
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void setActivity1(Activity activityObject) { activity1 = activityObject; }
    public void setActivity2(Activity activityObject) { activity2 = activityObject; }
    public void setActivity3(Activity activityObject) { activity3 = activityObject; }
    public void setActivity4(Activity activityObject) { activity4 = activityObject; }
    public void setActivity5(Activity activityObject) { activity5 = activityObject; }

    public void closeAllActivities() {
        if(activity1 != null) {
            activity1.finish();
        }
        if(activity2 != null) {
            activity2.finish();
        }
        if(activity3 != null) {
            activity3.finish();
        }
        if(activity4 != null) {
            activity4.finish();
        }
        if(activity5 != null) {
            activity5.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please show me with examples..i am new in android..and i dont know how to instance all the 5 activities in a common class

Comment: I will update my answer with this.

Comment: OK SparkYmat..i will work on that..thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: No problem. BTW, I notice that you haven't accepted many answers before. Could you please do that (for all the answers which helped you out) ?